# How do you detach the 2nd screen from within another screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I've accidentally attached to a 2nd GNU screen session from within an existing screen session and cannot detach or issue commands to the inner screen. I remember figuring out how to do that before but completely forgot and would like to keep it as reference.

One way is to detach the inner screen by doing `screen -dr` from shell, but what is the key combination to do that from within screen itself?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: If you've customized screen's escape character to something other than Ctrl-A, then the key sequence will be quite different. :)

Comment: Yeah, you're on your own with that.  <esc> a d may work; the man page is ambiguous, since it says that a sends the escape character, then clarifies that what it means by that is ctrl-A.  So it's a crapshoot.

Comment: Thanks, there we go, that's exactly what I remembered too and when I told it to my co-worker who was having this problem, he said it didn't work. Of course, now I found out he was pressing ctrl-a, ctrl-a, d, instead of ctrl-a, a, d.

Voted and closed.

Comment: If you use another escape character just double the second escape key. For example, I use Control+t and so I should press Control+t t d.

Comment: @brandizzi: Have you tested this?  Because I *deeply* suspect it is not the case, and that the sequence you would use is `ctrl-t a d`.

Comment: @chaos have _you_ tested this? I tried it right now and, yes, C-t t d detaches the screen inside a screen. Can you try it? Just add `escape ^Tt` to your `~/.screenrc`.

Comment: @brandizzi that didn't work for me, I had to do ctrl-t a d, so ymmv.

Answer (score 77):

`ctrl+a a` will pass the escape sequence (ctrl+a) to the sub-screen.. So, `ctrl+a a d` will do `ctrl+a d` in the sub-screen (detaching it)

It works with any screen command, for example `ctrl+a, a, c` will create a window in the  sub-screen

Comment: This one has a better explanation

Answer (score 7):

In general, if you have a screen `s3` within another screen `s2` within another screen `s1`, you can execute a command <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> in the screen:

- `s1` by doing: <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>
- `s2` by doing: <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>
- `s3` by doing: <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a hack for this. Just remotely de-attach the required screen by following command

```
screen -r -d screen_name or screen -rd screen_name
```

Comment: this one worked for me,
I could get my attached screen back and detach it!
Thanks